# ab показывает, что 99% запросов выполняется очень быстро и 1% крайне медленно

Tags: php, apache, benchmark

Помогите понять, что не так с веб-сервером и куда копать. Делаю *ab -c 5 -n 3000* на обычный hello world.
По результатам всегда 99% очень быстро и 1% очень медленно. C 47 ms до 9 секунд!

> Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
>
> 50%     47
>
> 66%     47
>
> 75%     62
>
> 80%     63
>
> 90%     63
>
> 95%     94
>
> 98%    297
>
> 99%   1063
>
> 100%   8688 (longest request)

Comment: Тяжёленький у вас `hello, world`, однако. Тестируете локально?

Comment: @vp_arth laravel чистая установка, страница приветствия. Ни строчки моего кода. Да локально. Но и удалённо так же. CPU кстати до 100% уходит когда выполняется это. Выполняется 44 секунд в среднем. RPS ~ 67

Comment: Ну, какой же это `hello, world`. Это целый фреймворк) Дебаг отключили? `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false)`

Comment: @vp_arth а разве есть разница? больше мучает вопрос почему все запросы выполняются быстро, а несколько Очень медленно.

Comment: Ну значит ресурсов где-то не хватило. xdebug - он знаете какой прожорливый)

Comment: Нет смысла проводить стресс-тестирование на отладочной сборке